# Run a function on the first day of every month

Tags: android, alarm

I want to run a function from my Android application at a fixed time (let's say 8am) on the first day of every month. The function, depending on user's preferences, will either serve a notification or start downloading a file over the Internet (both of which are already taken care of) or do nothing.

I tried using BroadcastReceiver with action `android.intent.action.DATE_CHANGED` but I read that it is fired only when user changes the date manually (although even then it worked the first 2-3 times I tried and then stopped working). I think an AlarmManager will be able to do what I need done but not really able to figure out how to implement it.

This should run whether or not my application is active/running. What is the optimum way to do this? Any supporting code will be appreciated.

Comment: Read more about background services: http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html then you can just get the system's date using a timer, and magic

Comment: @Aboca would it be then tracking the time continuously for the whole month waiting for magic to happen? Not an issue, but seems like too much load on processor for a small task. Shall use it for now, to meet the deadline.

Comment: The timer can be either an alarmmanager or a simple handler (should have used a better word), haven't really used alarmmanager but it could work out well for you. I suppose you have already look in to this but if you haven't read this: http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html I haven't used alarms so i can't give you a good start-off :s sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just start a service when start up. In the service,you could check the date in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use an alarm

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis()/*now*/, TIME_REPEATING, pendingIntent);
```

The TIME_REPEATING will be your calculate of the first day on the month, and the pendingIntent your service to run the task.

The unique hard work will be know how many time need to pass to the first day of the next month. But it's possible and very pausable to calculate.